# NuxtJS runtimeConfig to be save to a single js file on build?

Tags: vue.js, build, dotenv, nuxtjs, runtime-configuration

In my `nuxt.config.js`, I'm using runtimeConfig:

```js
export default {
  ssr: false,
  target: 'static',
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    apiURL: process.env.API_URL,
    emailAddress: process.env.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    wafURL: process.env.WAF_URL,
    appBuildYYYY: new Date().getFullYear(),
    appVersion: process.env.npm_package_version,
    appName: process.env.npm_package_name,
    appHomepage: process.env.npm_package_homepage
  }
```

When I `npx nuxt build` and look in my `/dist` folder, the resulting runtime configs are saved in the individual HTML pages (`/pageName/index.html`) inside a `<script>`.

Is there a way to build it where it becomes centrally stored? Like in a `/dist/_nuxt/runtimeConfig.js`?